What can I do about an A/C drain pipe that runs onto sidewalk?
My A/C pan drains onto the sidewalk from the PVC pipe in the photo. During Southern summers it becomes very slippery. The issue is that my entire house is surrounded by the same type of sidewalk, as shown in the photo. Unfortunately, this limits my options for redirecting the drainage. I’m looking for practical suggestions to handle this specific situation.






Would you rather run the pipe somewhere else or add nonslip to the sidewalk?

Definitely have considered just grabbing some nonslip pads from lowes like they use in restaurant kitchens. Ill make this my plan B in hopes that I come up with something better :)

Is your airhandler in the attic with the drain gravity fed out?  Or is the airhandler on the floor with a condensate pump forcing water up to the attic and out?

gravity fed out. once the pan fills up to the hole that's when it runs thru the PVC.

What's behind that gate?


The pipe on the wall begins high enough that you could run it at a gentle slope to the far end of the wall, or the other way behind the camera, to that end of the wall ... and eventually to a drain or a flower bed or lawn where it won't land on the walk.   You could learn to do this yourself, the cost will be low.

You could carve a small channel into the concrete for the water to flow through to the other side.  Very small, so it's not a trip hazard.  The flow from that pipe is small.  You would need hire someone to do this.   Cost will be more. You could do it with a rented tool but with no experience it's not a good idea.


Note: The trap - that curvy thing at the end - is important to the functioning of the air conditioner.  If you move the end of the pipe, put the trap back on it.  If you don't, turn it so it's not a trip hazard and likely to get broken off.
Edit: you added a photo showing the unit is in the attic. High enough you can definitely run the pipe anywhere.  Run it inside to nearer a better location, then outside as needed to a drain or flower bed anywhere around the house.   Worse case you could even run it over the path suspended by something stronger then down the fence.

@ jay613, The trap is a location thing.  In Florida those are always at the end of the drain outside.

@RMDman ah!   Is there a reason?   Edited accordingly.

In Fla. we call them lizard traps. They keep lizards and bugs from crawling up the pipe.

Route the pipe in the opposite direction to a grassy area. Depending on where the airhandler is inside, run a new drain line from it to an existing drain from a washer or sink. You could also cut a hole in the sidewalk and let a water go into the ground, not really good for your foundation though and the water still might overflow on to the sidewalk. Keep in mind, you'll probably need a trap if one doesn't already exist.

Not a bad suggestion, however in some areas it is against code to run an AC drain into  a house plumbing drain.

@RMDman  Yes, and in some areas it's against code to run it straight into the ground.  ;-)

I'd install a small round drain grate to allow the water through the sidewalk. There isn't enough flow volume to cause a foundation problem or sidewalk issues.

Rent a core drill. It should come with multiple sizes.

Pick up a simple round drain grate.

Cut a hole for the grate just deep enough for the grate to rest at or below flush with the concrete.

Cut a smaller hole for drainage through the slab.



image source
